# convert mapStateToProps to hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-hooks

i'm new to react (hooks) world learning by coding.
My question is related to MapStateToProps, i need to convert it to hooks, i'm stuck with one part of it (before 'currentItem')
here is my code:

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  sites: state.articles.sites,
  analysers: state.siteArticles.analysers,
  brokers: state.siteArticles.brokers,
  cameras: state.siteArticles.cameras,
  platforms: state.siteArticles.platforms,
  currentItem: {
    sites: state.selection.currentSite,
    cameras: state.selection.currentCamera,
    analysers: state.selection.currentAnalyser,
    platforms: state.selection.currentPlatform,
    brokers: state.selection.currentBroker,
  },
});
```

this is how i have converted it, i think its ok but dont know how to convert the beginning:

```js
 const currentItem = {
    sites: useSelector((state) => state.selection.currentSite),
    cameras: useSelector((state) => state.selection.currentCamera),
    analysers: useSelector((state) => state.selection.currentAnalyser),
    platforms: useSelector((state) => state.selection.currentPlatform),
    brokers: useSelector((state) => state.selection.currentBroker),
  };
```

Comment: without the first part i'm getting 'undefined'

Comment: That's not ok, you must call hooks on top level, refer to rules of hooks at docs.

Comment: i'm calling hooks on top level

Comment: calling `useSelector` at object scope is not a top-level... Check your lint warnings

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you trying and should do is:

```
// Inside function component
const currentItem = useSelector((state) => ({
  sites: state.articles.sites,
  analysers: state.siteArticles.analysers,
  brokers: state.siteArticles.brokers,
  cameras: state.siteArticles.cameras,
  platforms: state.siteArticles.platforms,
  currentItem: {
    sites: state.selection.currentSite,
    cameras: state.selection.currentCamera,
    analysers: state.selection.currentAnalyser,
    platforms: state.selection.currentPlatform,
    brokers: state.selection.currentBroker,
  },
}));
```

Comment: function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
 
    unselectActiveItem: {
      cameras: (site, id) => dispatch(clearCameraData(site, id)),
      brokers: (site, id) => dispatch(clearBrokerData(site, id)),

      sites: (site, id) => dispatch(clearSiteData(site, id)),
    },
    getItems: {
    
      brokers: (site) => dispatch(getBrokers(site)),
      cameras: (site) => dispatch(getCameras(site)),
      sites: (site) => dispatch(getSites()),
    },
  };
}

Comment: like this :   const unselectActiveItem = {
    cameras: (site, id) => dispatch(clearCameraData(site, id)),
    brokers: (site, id) => dispatch(clearBrokerData(site, id)),
    platforms: (site, id) => dispatch(clearPlatformData(site, id)),
    analysers: (site, id) => dispatch(clearAnalyserData(site, id)),
    sites: (site, id) => dispatch(clearSiteData(site, id)),
  }; ??

Comment: @waleedd32 don't do this. This code wasn't included in your question originally you can't just spring new questions once your original one is answered

Comment: @apokryfos your right i should have included it there

Comment: @waleedd32 you should use `useDispatch()` to get an instance of the dispatch. You don't need a `mapDispatchToProps` in this case you just dispatch actions in the component. In general you should really refer to [the manual](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks)

Comment: so i dont need to convert that 'mapDispatchToProps' code into hooks ?

Comment: Maybe you need but how its related to the original question, just resolve it and ask a new question